# First order differential equation of curve with two arbitrary constants

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

A differential equation of the family of curves for example $ Ax^2+By^2 = 1 $ can be found by differentiating the equation twice and eliminating $A$ and $B$.
But why can't we just differentiate once and solve the two equations for $A$ and $B$?

$$1.\ Ax^2+By^2 = 1 $$
$$2.\ Ax+Byy_1=0 $$
From 2,
$$ A=\frac{-Byy_1}{x} $$
Substituting in 1,
$$ B=\frac{1}{y^2-xyy_1} $$
Substituting in equation for A,
$$ A=\frac{-yy_1}{x(y^2-xyy_1)} $$
Substituting in 1,
$$ \frac{-yy_1x}{y^2-xyy_1}+\frac{y^2}{y^2-xyy_1}=1 $$
Where $y_1=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ independant parameters?

Comment: @samjoe yes. Arbitrary

Comment: Then your method is fine

Comment: My high school teacher says it's wrong, and that there has to be a second order differential term for it to be a valid differential equation

Comment: You should make clearer the objective of your work : why do you need these constraints ? What are your future solution curves made for ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm sorry, what constraints?

Comment: I call $2.\ Ax+Byy_1=0$ a constraint. But the issue is not there: where does this equation come from ? What is it related to ? The equation of the tangent at point $ (1,y_1)$ to the (ellipse) curve with equation 1.\ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $y_1$ is the first derivative

Comment: @samjoe The method of the asker "is fine... " I would say not contradictory, because, as pointed out by Gerry Myerson, it gives \tfrac11=1 :)

Comment: @Jean Ah now I see! Just taking denominator to other side shows it. SO this will happen everytime when we have the order of differential equation less than number of arbitrary constants in original equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "differential equation" simplifies to $1=1$.

Comment: So why does that even happen when all I did was solve two equations in two variables and what's the difference when I differentiate twice and use three equations to find the differential equation? @GerryMyerson

Comment: If you had one equation in one variable, say, the variable $A$ in $Ax=17$, you could solve it for $A$, but you couldn't eliminate $A$ to get an equation with just $x$ in it, right? Same thing here, just one level up. But if you had two equations, say, $Ax=17$ and $Ay=42$, then you could eliminate $A$ to get an equation relating $x$ and $y$.